# Given variance covariance matrix for log parameters, find standard deviation of parameters

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, covariance

Suppose I have a variance-covariance matrix for three (log) parameters
$$
\text{Var}\left[\left(\log\theta, \log \phi, \log \psi\right)\right] = \begin{pmatrix} 
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \Sigma_{13} \\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \Sigma_{23} \\
\Sigma_{31} & \Sigma_{32} & \Sigma_{33}\end{pmatrix}
$$
How do I find the standard deviations for $\theta$, $\phi$ and $\psi$? I can see two ways of finding it, but they give different results

- $\exp\left(\sqrt{\Sigma_{ii}}\right)$
- $\sqrt{\exp\left(\Sigma_{ii}\right)}$

which one is correct and why?

Comment: What multivariate distribution are you assuming for $\log{\theta}$, $\log\phi$, and $\log\psi$?  A multivariate normal?  You can't get the associated parameters for $\theta$, $\phi$, and $\psi$ without specifying that.

Comment: Yes a multivariate normal. I realized that probably the solution is given [here](https://www.casact.org/pubs/forum/15spforum/Halliwell.pdf)